# OpenRGB Kingston fury beast

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a Msi z490 gaming plus board with Kingston fury beast ram (I am on Ubuntu 20.04).

I used mystic lights in w10, to switch everything off. Therefore, I have followed the installation guides from git for openrgb. I can control everything except the ram.

I followed every step except the kernel patch. Do you know what I could do to have it work? Thanks.

The Mobo switch kills all LEDs but not the ram, is there any alternative way? (also definitive to switch this ram off)

Edit: I reverted back to w11 and there openrgb works as it should detecting everything. My cpu is i9-10850k

PS: the log file of openrgb is this one

```
[Info:] ------------------------------------------------------
[Info:] |             Detecting I2C interfaces               |
[Info:] ------------------------------------------------------
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-3 Device 8086:9BC5 Subsystem: 1462:7C75
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-10 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-1 Device 8086:9BC5 Subsystem: 1462:7C75
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-8 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-6 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-13 Device 0000:0000 Subsystem: 0000:0000
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-4 Device 8086:9BC5 Subsystem: 1462:7C75
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-11 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-2 Device 8086:9BC5 Subsystem: 1462:7C75
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-0 Device 8086:06A3 Subsystem: 1462:7C75
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-9 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-7 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-14 Device 0000:0000 Subsystem: 0000:0000
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-5 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] Registering I2C interface: /dev/i2c-12 Device 1002:6810 Subsystem: 174B:E270
[Info:] ------------------------------------------------------
...
```